# Unreal Engine 4 - Dropdownlist of images

Tags: image, drop-down-menu, combobox, widget, unreal-engine4

I have a question.

I am working on a game project using Unreal Engine 4,

I wanted to add a drop down list that consists of images.

I managed to add the combobox (ddl) widget but I don't know how to fill it with icons.

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using UMG blueprints or Slate widgets?

Comment: what is the difference ? Excuse me but I am still new to UE4 :/

Comment: Then you are probably using the UMG blueprints. I'm sorry, but I do not think there is an easy way to add icons to the combobox. UMG is relatively new and is currently not very flexible for these sort of things. You will probably have to build it yourself using primitive components like CanvasPanels, a Scrollbox and Images.